# Ruby on rails: Helper method returns multiple values to views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a helper method that returns around 10 values/variables to a view. Calling this method in the view is a mess if i need to make use of local variables and not the instance variables returned by the helper.

I also don't want to make use of multiple helper methods for all these different values as it will duplicate my code.

For eg: 
example_helper.rb

```
  def multiple_return_values
    return a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
  end
```

example_view.html.erb

```
  <% a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = multiple_return_values %>
```

OR

```
  <% values = multiple_return_values %>
  <% values[0] %>
  <% values[1] %>
  .
  .
  .
  <% values[9] %>
```

I don't want to use these above blocks of code(for example_view.html.erb). Neither i want to use instance variables coming from the helper. I want to use only local variables in views.

What is the best way to use these multiple values returned from the helper in the view using only local variables?

Comment: the other way to do this is you can return open struct instance and get the value from that by `my_struct = multiple_return_values` then `my_struct.x`  `my_struct.y` `my_struct.z`...

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** My preference is **Solution 1.1** if only few returned values, and **Solution 1.2** if loooooads of returned values

### Solution 1.1

```
def multiple_return_values
  # ...
  return {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    c: c,
    d: d,
    e: e,
    f: f,
    g: g,
    h: h,
    i: i,
    j: j
  }
end
```

### Solution 1.2

OR if you prefer non-repetition of "keys" and "values" from Solution 1.1, then:

```
def multiple_return_values
  # ...
  local_variables_to_be_returned = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f, :g, :h, :i, :j]
  return Hash[local_variables_to_be_returned.map{|v| [v, binding.local_variable_get(v)]}]
end
```

#### Usage

Then in your views,

```
<% returned_values = multiple_returned_values -%>

<%= returned_values[:a] %>
<%= returned_values[:b] %>
<%= returned_values[:g] %>
```

### Solution 2

See @HankPhung's comment: to return an `OpenStruct` instance instead of a `Hash`, then you'll just simply use `OpenStruct.new(HASH)`:

```
def multiple_return_values
  # ...
  local_variables_to_be_returned = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f, :g, :h, :i, :j]
  return OpenStruct.new(
    Hash[local_variables_to_be_returned.map{|v| [v, binding.local_variable_get(v)]}]
  )
end
```

#### Usage

Then in your views,

```
<% returned_values = multiple_return_values -%>

<%= returned_values.a %>
<%= returned_values.b %>
<%= returned_values.g %>
```

### Solution 3

*NOT-recommended; only very case-specific usage*

You can directly pass in the `binding` as the return value

```
def multiple_return_values_binding
  # ...
  return binding
end
```

#### Usage

Then in your views,

```
<% somebinding = multiple_return_values_binding -%>

<%= somebinding.local_variable_get(:a) %>
<%= somebinding.local_variable_get(:b) %>
<%= somebinding.local_variable_get(:g) %>
```